# Trying convert do-while loop to while loop

Tags: java, loops

I trying convert do-while to while loop and program even compile, but nothing happens.
Original do-while loop code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String coin, again;
        int flip, streak = 0;

        do
        {
            flip = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*2);

            if ( flip == 1 )
                coin = "HEADS";
            else
                coin = "TAILS";

            System.out.println( "You flip a coin and it is... " + coin );

            if ( flip == 1 )
            {
                streak++;
                System.out.println( "\tThat's " + streak + " in a row...." );
                System.out.print( "\tWould you like to flip again (y/n)? " );
                again = keyboard.next();
            }
            else
            {
                streak = 0;
                again = "n";
            }
        } while ( again.equals("y") );

        System.out.println( "Final score: " + streak );
    }
}
```

How it looks like after I trying to do while loop from do-while loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinFlip2
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String coin, again;
        int flip, streak = 0;
        again = keyboard.next();
        //flip = 1 + (int) (Math.random()*2);

        while ( again.equals("y") )
        {
            flip = 1 + (int) (Math.random()*2);
            if ( flip == 1)
            {
                coin = "HEADS";
            }
            else
            {
                coin = "TAILS";
            System.out.println( "You flip a coin and it is..." + coin );
            }
            if ( flip == 1)
            {
                streak++;
                System.out.println("\tThat's " + streak + " in a row....");
                System.out.print( "\tWould you like to flip again (y/n)? ");
                //again = keyboard.next();
            }
            else
            {
                streak = 0;
                again = "n";
            }
            System.out.println( "Final score: " + streak);
        }
    }
}
```

Code compile without problem but I see blank output after running it.

Comment: Do-While loops are guaranteed to run at least once, while loops are not. You get a blank output because you are waiting for keyboard input on line 11

Comment: You can't. `do-while`loops and `while` loops are non-interchangeable, at least without an extra Boolean variable. Why are you even trying?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you never initialize `again` variable to `y`, so it never matches condition to enter `while`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String coin, again = "y";
    int flip, streak = 0;
    // flip = 1 + (int) (Math.random()*2);

    while (again.equals("y")) {
        flip = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        if (flip == 1) {
            coin = "HEADS";
        } else {
            coin = "TAILS";
            System.out.println("You flip a coin and it is..." + coin);
        }
        if (flip == 1) {
            streak++;
            System.out.println("\tThat's " + streak + " in a row....");
            System.out.print("\tWould you like to flip again (y/n)? ");
            again = keyboard.next();
            // again = keyboard.next();
        } else {
            streak = 0;
            again = "n";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Final score: " + streak);
    keyboard.close();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
That's 1 in a row....
Would you like to flip again (y/n)? y
You flip a coin and it is...TAILS
Final score: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your `again` with `"y"`:

```
String coin, again;
int flip, streak = 0;
again = "y";
...
```

and ask for keyboard entry in your while loop:

```
if ( flip == 1)
{
    streak++;
    System.out.println("\tThat's " + streak + " in a row....");
    System.out.print( "\tWould you like to flip again (y/n)? ");
    again = keyboard.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that rocks!
Is I understand correctly that if 
    again = keyboard.next();
is commented here, then program always type "y" here for me automatically?

Comment: Well it won't change `again` at all so you'll run into an infinate loop!